# Xcode keeps reverting my Core Data model to an older version

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an Xcode project with a core data model. I have added a new model version to the project and marked it as the current version in xcode.

[image]

This works fine and my app will perform the lightweight migration and open up the database.

The problem is when I close down Xcode and then open up the project again, the model reverts to the older version. This is not shown in Xcode as the green arrow is still against Model.1.0.6 but I can clearly see this if I look at the .xcdatamodeld file.

[image]

When I start the app after reopening I get exceptions due to missing entities. If I use the project navigator to select the current model version as 'Model.xcdatamodel' and then toggle it back to 'Model.1.0.6.xcdatamodel' and then start the app again it works fine again.

I have to do this every time I reopen the project. It looks like Xcode is reverting to the old model version every time I open the project for some reason but I can't figure out why.

Comment: A little bit of a shot in the dark, but did you try renaming the new model without the periods? i.e. 'Model_1_0_6'. It might be parsing out the periods.

Comment: have you checked in your file inspector -> model version -> current?

Comment: @akash Yes Inspector>current shows the correct version.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose gave it a shot, didn't help though but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could fix this was by deleting the model and adding a new model with a different name. I then manually copied in the xml schema from both model versions and it now works.

Not really sure what was going on somehow the model had gotten itself in to a state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure both model versions are set to the latest XCode format?  I have found some odd issues in other areas of XCode when there were competing file versions...

Check under "Tools Version" for each model, and set Minimum to XCode 4.5 for both.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, changed them both to 4.5, saved, closed, reopened but problem persists.